# Are the Health/Agility/Magic Elixirs worth buying?

Tags: league-of-legends

Are the elixirs (not the potions) worth investing in for their stats?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. You need to be extremely fed for it to be justifiable early. Usually you will buy wards and continue building items. Elixirs are not worth it early/mid game because the 3 minutes of boosted stats is not worth the amount of gold you have to spend to get them. Late game when you have gold to spend with nothing else to buy, you always should stack up on them, as they do help.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends. I myself when am playing AP champion if I have my luck with me and make a lot of gold and everytime when I have 250 gold, sometimes I buy the Magic elixir, but I drink it when I go gank or start fighting someone.

If you do it, don't use the elixir at the shop - use it when you are sure to use it. After all, its a boost and its helpful. Try it sometime and you will find your answer and you will decide if it's worth it or not :)

Answer (score 1):

The cooldown reduction of the magic elixir can be very helpful in laning/sustain/ganking.

The health buff from the health elixir is useful once you have most of your late game items finished. It can also be used when dying from a dot (i.e: Teemo poison) to give you 250 instant health whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are very worth buying as they syenergize very well with all champions needs.

Blue elixir's cooldown and aditional AP works lovely with champions who excell at dishing out tons of damage. The more skills which require AP and the better AP scaling that they have make this potion crucial for moments when you are team fighting, or just simply bursting your enemy solo mode. It makes you scarier and this works very well for you as you are probably playing AP carry at mid lane which essentially depends on what champion can get the upper hand and burst the enemy champion down. It works as a clutch for those moments when you are fed or farmed and you can waste 250g for the extra tipping power which can win games. It goes very well after you get your Rabadons Deathcap. It is keen to note that as AP champions specialize in bursting the enemy down in an instant so blue elixirs are very self payed because the additional damage is significant and the swift burst that will happen only require you to get a good grasp on your enemy unlike other potions like the green one which works best in sustain.

Green elixir is allso very very powerful and syenergises with any champion with built in attack speed , critical strike boosters or strong scaling ad skills that proc on hit effects.It is not a viable purchase in early game but gets very strong in mid - late game as you by this phase have allready got your attack speed, crit and attack damage items. Every aditional attack speed boost counts because late game fights can happen in a blink of an eye and you are the backbone of destruction of your team so the quicker you lock onto someone and DPS him down without dieing the better. It is probably the most gold worthy potion late game because your normal attacks proc everything from lifesteal to armor reduction so one thing  leads to another and attack speed helps you lifesteal up quicker , shred armor faster , increase your crit rate and thus adding a chance factor to increase your damage exponentially working as a very good game changer.

Red elixirs work not as potions of warfare but they act more as a life saving potion which can clutch you out of a close call with an instant 250 hp. It isnt very famous in the current meta as you have various methods of escaping from your enemy easily. It is probably the least gold worthy potion as it does not make the AD scale with your level. You wont probably find yourself in need of these 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Buy them only when your inventory is completely full,otherwise they are almost always waste of gold (aka not worth buying as saving money for items is more important).

Tip: When you buy elixirs with your inventory being full they are automatically used on you.